# Why eclipse doesn't recompile last changes made to my Java classes?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a simple file with just 1 line that prints "Hello World" inside main. I execute it and it prints "Hello World" on eclipse console. Now when I change the string to 
"Bye world" it still prints "Hello World". Infact if I cause a syntax error by modifying println to prrrintln. it still prints "Hello World". What can cause eclipse to not use the latest file ? 
When I try to run it from command line, I get the following error:

```
bin> java WordBreakProblem.class 
Error: Could not find or load main class WordBreakProblem.class
```

Is there a correlation between two issues here?

Comment: Maybe you have Project->Build Automatically unchecked.

Comment: You aren't running the code you think you're running.  Not an Eclipse user so not sure exactly how your run configurations is set up.  Are you building a .jar that you're running your code out of?  Is that .jar getting rebuilt every time your source changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Have Build Automatically checked

[image]

2.
The correct way to run WordBreakProblem class is

```
java WordBreakProblem
```

instead of

```
java WordBreakProblem.class
```

Also make sure you compile the java source code into WordBreakProblem.class by using

```
javac WordBreakProblem.java
```

before doing step 2.

3.
If the code still doesn't refresh, try "clean".

[image]

Comment: This option is horrible when you work with several projects and classes e.g. 10+ projects and over 1000 classes.

Comment: You may close unrelated projects if you have 10+ projects.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse by default recompiles the projects after saving a change. This is noticed by Project > Build Automatically. If this option is unchecked, eclipse won't recompile the workspace after saving a small change. IMO this is option is useless when you have too many projects/files and recompilation can take several minutes.

If you have disabled this option (like me), then check this other option in Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching > Build (if required) before launching:

[image: Build before launching]

If this option is disabled, then no matter how many times you change the classes or resources in the project, you will have to manually fire a build for the project(s) before launching it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you re-saved the code? In eclipse you need to save the changes made otherwise it will run what is previously saved. Or potentially try rebuilding the path if it is not saved to the right area.