# How to remote debug the changes on-fly

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, war, remote-debugging

I use java programming language, eclipse IDE and the project I work on is a war application, after making some changes I do mvn clean install -u and after the war gets generated, I will deploy it to tomcat and set the remote `set JPDA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8082,server=y,suspend=n` and start Catalina and start the debug server. when I make some changes and do debugging,  debugger doesnt show the chnages I did after build in order to reflect the changes   I need to go to all this process which takes about 10+ minutes I wanted to know is there a way I can do this on fly.

Comment: Are you recompiling the file *in Eclipse* while the debugging session is active? (that's all you should have to do, and it shouldn't take 10 minutes)

Comment: @dnault Recompiling means mvn clean install you mean while debugger is on?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262686/why-eclipse-doesnt-recompile-last-changes-made-to-my-java-classes/33262810) makes me think that by default Eclipse will automatically recompile your project files whenever you save the files. If you do this during a debug session, Eclipse should send the new version of the compiled class files to the remote JVM. The caveat is that this only works for code changes, not changes to resource files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load changes on the fly in tomcat, build directly to the webapps directory of tomcat.

A simple way to achieve this is make a symbolic link with 'ln -s' command, so the webapps/appname/WEB-INF/classes directory in your tomcat links to the target/classes directory of your project. This supposes you work on Linux or Mac OS.

Comment: but webapps directory doesnt have a pom how to build it?

Comment: If you use a symbolic link, you still build your project. The webapps/appname/WEB-INF/classes will point to to the target/classes of your project.

Comment: but in web apps there are no .java files

Comment: Keep your project as is, just add a symbolic link in the webapps/appname/WEB-INF/ directory named 'classes' that points to the target/classes directory of your project. I don't know how to explain it better. Have you checked what a symbolic link is ?

Comment: I have researched about symbolic links. Can you walk through with few screenshots of your IDE what ever you use. It would be easy to understand.

Comment: for JSP and JS I can do debugger; statement I open the deployment file generated by war and link to visual studio and make on fly changes But for java I cannot do it.